# Messageboard user messages Marionette js

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js, marionette, messageboard

I believe I have a good understanding of Marionette and Backbone, but the following issue has me stumped.  I'm trying to display a message board using marionette item views within a collection view, and I have a way that works, but I'm unhappy with the outcome as it ends up with me calling reset on a new collection after processing my initial array of messages.

Let's say I have an array, or backbone Collection, of messages from a web server. e.g.

```
[{ user : "Alice", timestamp : 1,  body : "message1" },
 { user : "Alice", timestamp : 5,  body : "message2" },
 { user : "Bob",   timestamp : 10, body : "message3" },
 { user : "Alice", timestamp : 20, body : "message4" }]   etc.
```

I would like to display the messages in batches of user messages, so I would see:

- Alice

  - message1
  - message2
- Bob

  - message3
- Alice

  - message4

How can I best achieve this using Marionette?  I currently perform a single pass of all messages, building a new array that looks like the following:

```
[{ user : "Alice", messages : ["message1", "message2"] },
 { user : "Bob",   messages : ["message3"] },
 { user : "Alice", messages : ["message4"] }]
```

I then make a new Collection, and call reset with the above array.  This 'reset' takes a long time (27 seconds!!) for a large (~250) number of messages.  Each batch of user messages is a new ItemView and I use handlebars in my template to iterate over the messages array for that batch.

I also want this to cope with another message being appended to the end of  the initial array, and have the CollectionView update automatically.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you modify your backend?

Comment: Each call to the server returns *all* messages, or just the most recent?

Comment: Let's say the last 10 messages.  The server has a scrollback feature too, so I can then request the 10 before that, then the 10 before that etc. I can't really modify the backend.

Comment: Do you still require a solution for this?

Comment: Yes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of reorganizing the collection, can you work with it as is? I.e. build the display so that, when you find additional "Alice" messages, you append them to her `ul` or `div`, rather than getting them all in order first?